# Find a function $f$ and a number $a$ such that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(x + 1)}{x} = f'(a)$

Tags: calculus

Firstly, can someone clarify what exactly the question is asking me to do? Often my biggest problem in calculus isn't the math, but the questions seem so overly complex and technical that it is unclear to me what to do. Any advice for this?

Secondly, this is the problem I need help with:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ln(x + 1)}{x} = f'(a)$$

Answer (score 1):

Literally, the question is asking you to find a function $f(x)$ and a number $a$ so that the value of the limit on the left is the value of the function on the right.  There's lots of ways to make that work, of course; practically, what they want you to do is note that they have a derivative on the right (as $f'(a)$) and they're hoping that you were paying enough attention when they went over the definition of derivative so that you can identify the left-hand side as the derivative of a particular function at a particular point.

Comment: Okay, the limit is the derivative of a specific point, I got that and I understand it abstractly. But how is that useful to me? I don't see the application of that notion.

Comment: The application to this question, you mean?  The definition of the derivative is the limit, as $x\to 0$, of $(f(x+a)-f(a))/x$.  If the top has to match $f(x+a)$, and it looks like $\ln(x+1)$, what do you think $f$ and $a$ have to match up to be?  (You then just have to verify that $f(a)=0$, since it vanished.)